# Function defined in head not recognized in body?

Tags: javascript, import, head

Hi all I'm learning javascript and have run into a problem when defining a function in head utilizing imported functions:

```
<script type="module">
import {g1} From './scripts/main.js';

myFunction(){
do something, g1 is called
}
</script>
```

when I call myFunction in body I get a myFunction() not defined error:

```
<script>
myFunction();
</script>
```

My understanding is this should work, am I making a mistake with the type attribute in head?

Comment: You have a script `type="module"`. It's executed in modules cope, and thus not in the global sclope.

Answer (score 1):

In JS the scope of a given code is executed simply like so:

**(1) Global scope > (2) Module scope and then the > (3) Function scope**

Meaning that you try to access a module scope variable/function in the global scope, you need to restructure you code someway. Your options are:

- Either to put the code within the same module
- Or find a way to import one module into the other one

Comment: Can the imported code not simply be made to execute in global? Must it necessarily be executed in the module scope? Thanks for the response!